# jQuery / backbone.js - delay function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, dom-events, settimeout

I have a `#search` element, which when the `keyup` event occurs should fire a function. This function should only fire if `keyup` hasn't occurred in a set amount of time (say 500 milliseconds for example). This will prevent search results from updating every letter that is pressed. The problem is that with backbone.js, I have my events in a hash and the one that is applicable looks like:

`'keyup #search' : 'setSearch'`

which calls the `setSearch()` function when the `keyup` event occurs. I'm not really clear on how to handle it at this point. I've tried a variety of things, but nothing can maintain the timer past the function ending.

I have something like so:

```
setSearch: function(event) {
            var timer = window.setTimeout( function() {
                // run function here
                alert('fired');
            }, 500);
    },
```

rather than the `alert('fired')`, I'll have my own function run. I can see why this code doesn't work (a timer is set for every `keyup` event that occurs. But I still don't have a clear idea on what else I could try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance variable in your view that stores the timer ID, then you can stop it and restart it as needed:

```
setSearch: function(event) {
    var self = this;
    if(self.timer)
        clearTimeout(self.timer);
    self.timer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('fired');
        self.timer = null;
    }, 500);
}
```

So, if the timer is already running, you call [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout) to stop it, start a new timer, and store the timer ID in `self.timer` (AKA `this.timer`). You'll also want to reset the stored timer ID in the timer's callback function or your `setSearch` won't do anything after its timer has fired once. And all the `self` business is just to capture `this` for use in the timer's callback function.

Answer (score 18):

What you are looking for is actually a function provided to you from underscore.js (a  requirement of Backbone)

```
 setSearch: _.throttle(function() {
                //Do Stuff
              }, 500),
```

In a nutshell, this returns a new form of the anonymous function that can only be called once every 500ms.  You will likely have to tweak the timing to your needs.

More Info:
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle

Comment: user1243645's comment: "I encountered a similar requirement in my project. I just wanted to add, in response to Skylar Anderson's post about `_.throttle`, I've actually found that [`_.debounce()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce) works better for my needs."

Comment: Debounce is far better than throttle for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing the updating of search results on every `keyup` is exactly the kind of situation that  Underscore's `_.debounce(function, wait)` function is meant to deal with. The [underscore documentation for _.debounce()](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) states:

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed `function` which will postpone its execution until after `wait` milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving.

Your refactored code would look as simple as:

```
setSearch: function(event) {
    _.debounce(doSomething, 300);
},
```

Comment: "which will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked" - doesn't work in the case of a 'search field' because you don't want it to do a search on the first keyup, you want to wait 3 keyups etc before doing the search - especially for large sets. But in the event of fire something then wait fire again, yes it's great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your event handler events to be able to maintain whether or not an event has `recentlyFired`, you probably want to wrap your handler into a closure and maintain that status. The status should be changed to true when an event has fired, and reset to false after a delay of 500ms.

```
setSearch: function( ) {
    var firedRecently = false;
    return function(event) {
        if (firedRecently) {
            // it has fired recently. Do you want to do something here?
        } else {
            // not fired recently
            firedRecently = true;
            // run your function here
            alert('fired');
            var resetStatus = window.setTimeout( function () {
                firedRecently = false;
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}( );
```